# Unique key my app in ios

Tags: ios

Hi I need unique key which is generated during run time of my app. That is no device authentication all the device should generate same key because I need to hardcore it in my server. Any device with my app want to generate unique key to send request to server to ensure the request is came from my app. I think any key can be generate using my App store certificate, is it possible?. Because all the device with my app should contain only same certificate.

Pls help me to out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method for generating unique keys

```
-(NSString *)guid {
    // create a new UUID which you own
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

    // create a new CFStringRef (toll-free bridged to NSString) that you own
    NSString *uuidString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuid);

    // release the UUID
    CFRelease(uuid);

    return uuidString;
}
```

Comment: IS All the device should give same value and it is accepted by the apple?

Comment: This method is accepted by Apple. No, devices will not generate the same ID.

Comment: Then you need a way to share the IDs generated if you need the same ID to propagate across devices. How many IDs do you need? How are they going to be used? It looks like your question is misleading and needs to be rewritten if you need all devices to have the same IDs.

Comment: No restriction to devices.  Then my app is business app with push notification.

Answer (score 0):

You may use system method from Apple

NSString *strApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

Comment: IS All the device should give same value and it is accepted by the apple? Then ios version effect the value?  that means ios 6 and ios 7 should give same value?

Comment: Most answers here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor

Comment: Ok it return same value for all the device and in all version?

Comment: Device to device it chaning I need same key from all the device and all version of device with my app.

Comment: You may use this code to keep this key between app install/uninstall session: NSString *appName=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];
    
    NSString *strApplicationUUID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:appName account:@"incoding"];
    if (strApplicationUUID == nil)
    {
        strApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
        [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:appName account:@"incoding"];
    }
    
    return strApplicationUUID;